# How to add shadow on NSSearchField

Tags: macos, shadow, nssearchfield

I want to overwrite the NSSearchField class and make it seems like
[image]

I have looked into the Apple's Document, and found out that NSSearchField is inherited from NSTextField, which is inherited from NSControl, and NSControl itself is inherited from NSView.

So, NSTextField could correspond to setShadow: method, however, I've tried to set an NSShadow on the NSSearchField instance, but nothing happened actually.

Could anyone tell to how to get the shadow effect? Thanks~

Comment: Can you name a Mac app whose search field you're trying to emulate? Your screenshot helps, but an interactive example search field would help even more.

Comment: I'm afraid I have found an app with a customized NSSearchField yet. My goal is to find a way to set gray shadow on top half of the NSSearchField, while set white shadow on the bottom half. It's not necessarily to emulate exactly what the screenshot show, but please show to the way to do so, thanks.Sorry for my poor english, hope you could understand.

Comment: Well the problem resides in some legacy... The text fields are old and draw based on styles, and don't respect shadows... You can subclass the cell and draw it any way you like... But that may be overkill... The easiest way may be to use a text cell without a border, and an image of what you want the cell to look like.

Comment: I've tried to overwrite the NSSearchFieldCell, but the problem is, if I do not call super draw method, the magnifier won't be drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NSTextField with NSShadow

```
// Modify theTextField so that its NSShadow will be visible.
theTextField.wantsLayer = YES ;
theTextField.bezeled = NO ;
theTextField.drawsBackground = NO ;

NSShadow* redShadow = [NSShadow new] ;
redShadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(2, 2) ;
redShadow.shadowColor = [NSColor redColor] ;
theTextField.shadow = redShadow ;
```

That results in:  [image: Grey text, red shadow]

In my experience with NSShadows and NSTextFields/NSSearchFields, the shadow doesn't appear unless the NSTextField is not bezeled and does not draw its background, and the blinking cursor is shadowed along with the text before it.

*Edit:*

### Subclass NSSearchField, override `drawRect:`

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSShadow* redShadow = [NSShadow new] ;
    redShadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(2, -2) ;
    redShadow.shadowColor = [NSColor redColor] ;

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState] ;
    self.wantsLayer = YES ;     // or NO
    [redShadow set] ;
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect] ;
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState] ;
}
```

That results in:  [image: wantsLayer = YES]  [image: wantsLayer = NO].
I assume you don't want the magnifying glass icon or X button to have shadows, so you could:

### Add a second NSSearchField behind the original

This would probably be easier to do in Interface Builder, but here's code that would accomplish this in an NSSearchField subclass.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib] ;

    NSSearchField* shadowSearchField = [NSSearchField new] ;
    [self.superview addSubview:shadowSearchField  positioned:NSWindowBelow  relativeTo:self ] ;
    shadowSearchField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
    shadowSearchField.editable = NO ;

    float horizontalOffset = -2 ;
    float verticalOffset   = -2 ;
    [self.superview addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:shadowSearchField  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading  multiplier:1  constant:horizontalOffset ] ] ;
    [self.superview addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:shadowSearchField  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop      multiplier:1  constant:verticalOffset ] ] ;
    [self.superview addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:shadowSearchField  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth    multiplier:1  constant:0 ] ] ;
    [self.superview addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:shadowSearchField  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight   multiplier:1  constant:0 ] ] ;
}
```

That results in:  [image: with focusRing]  and  [image: without focusRing], which seem closest to what you want, if you can tweak the position and color of the second NSSearchField.

Comment: I've tried to set the NSSearchField's bezeled and drawsBackground to NO, but it only add the shadow to the magnifier and the text I input, as well as the cursor. My goal is to set the shadow on the border of the NSSearchField

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. Also the solution's a little bit tricky, it works!